# there was no shortcut icon after the installation of android studio

Tags: android-studio, installation

After I install the android studio I cant see the shortcut of the android studio or the icon to open it again what should I do?

Comment: Windows 8.1 sir

Comment: Check this path "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe"

Comment: and Check this "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

Select studio64.exe

Right click on it

click on send to Desktop